# after triggering a branch in wit.ai using weather the initial action no longer works

Tags: branch, action, weather, wit.ai

I followed the quick start guide and was able to complete it.

However, when i tried testing the branch action then followed by the initial action where the parameters are complete it keeps on responding with a question triggered by the branch action.

How do I resolve this?

[image: Chat bot]

Comment: thanks Youssef, that did the trick. it wasn't clear that I can't do that on the chat simulator. thanks again

Comment: you're welcome, i made it as answer for reference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your second scenario where the user doesn't specify a location should go into a sparate story:
From Wit.ai documentation:

> You will teach Wit by example, and each example conversation is called a Story

So from what i understand a story needs to handle one initial input.